# conditional update mySQL entrys using multiple rows

Tags: mysql, database, conditional-statements

So I have a database, which has as columns: `name`, `uid` and `points`.
Basically I want to decrease the points on one entry by `100`, but only if `points > 100`. But at the same time I want to increase the points on another entry by `100`, but also only if `points > 100` on the first entry.

```
IF <user1_points > 100> : Increase user2_points by 100, decrease user1_points by 100
ELSE: do nothing
```

I tried looking around, but I couldnt find a good solution (only some with `EXISTS`, or not for `mySQL/InnoDB` but I need a specific condition)

My database looks like this:

```
| name | uid | points |
|------+-----+--------|
| Foo  |  1  |  100   |
|------+-----+--------|
| Bar  |  2  |  200   |
|------+-----+--------|
```

and my expected result is:

```
| name | uid | points |
|------+-----+--------|
| Foo  |  1  |  200   |
|------+-----+--------|
| Bar  |  2  |  100   |
|------+-----+--------|
```

but only if `points(uid=1) > 100`. Otherwise just do nothing.

I am basically looking for the propper way to express the phrase (pseudocode):

`IF uid=2.points >= 100 THEN SET uid=1.points += 100 AND uid=1.points -= 100`

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result  ..

Answer (score 1):

I think you're just looking to `UPDATE` certain fields.

Try this syntax:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET points = points + 100
WHERE points > 100
AND some_condition;
```

Similarly, you can subtract the points, when it meets your other condition

```
UPDATE table_name
SET points = points - 100
WHERE points > 100
AND some_other_condition;
```

More here:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Comment: That `WHERE` is kind of the problem. How do I select from another row inside a WHERE clause?
Because I basically need to say `points(uid=1) = points(uid=1) + 100` and `points(uid=2) = points(uid=2) - 100`

Comment: What is your condition?

Comment: AND name = 'Foo'

Comment: So basically the best way is to just call 2 querys? But then still, I have to call the row by the column UID. So how would I say `update ... set points = points + 100 if points > 100 where uid=2`? I could not really figure out a way to express that